# Creating bar graph of event occurrences for each month of several years in excel

Tags: excel, date, graph

I have a long list of dates (about 2000) in an excel spreadsheet and I want to see how many of these dates lie within particular years (and roughly which part of the year also if possible). I know how to make basic graphs in excel, but I'm not sure how to make a bar graph that uses dates. Any suggestions?

I can obviously split events in day, month, and year and then use count to count the amount of each year, but this would not show the placement of the event within the year in the final graph.

```
20/03/2000
2/04/2000
3/04/2000
26/05/2000
7/06/2000
20/06/2000
22/06/2000
10/07/2000
12/07/2000
22/07/2000
2/08/2000
8/08/2000
11/08/2000
14/08/2000
15/08/2000
12/09/2000
15/09/2000
20/09/2000
25/09/2000
2/10/2000
22/10/2000
24/10/2000
25/10/2000
27/10/2000
1/11/2000
10/11/2000
13/11/2000
16/11/2000
18/11/2000
20/11/2000
25/11/2000
27/11/2000
3/12/2000
6/12/2000
20/12/2000
21/12/2000
22/12/2000
4/01/2001
7/01/2001
11/01/2001
24/01/2001
25/01/2001
2/02/2001
4/02/2001
9/02/2001
12/02/2001
13/02/2001
20/02/2001
21/02/2001
2/03/2001
11/04/2001
19/04/2001
20/04/2001
21/04/2001
24/04/2001
27/04/2001
28/04/2001
2/05/2001
3/05/2001
5/05/2001
12/05/2001
13/06/2001
20/06/2001
25/06/2001
3/07/2001
5/07/2001
18/07/2001
20/07/2001
21/07/2001
22/07/2001
25/07/2001
4/08/2001
5/08/2001
9/08/2001
10/08/2001
11/08/2001
12/08/2001
13/08/2001
31/08/2001
11/09/2001
12/09/2001
17/09/2001
3/10/2001
10/10/2001
18/10/2001
21/10/2001
23/10/2001
4/11/2001
5/11/2001
17/11/2001
22/11/2001
23/11/2001
27/11/2001
29/11/2001
3/12/2001
```

Comment: If you add another column containing the number 1 next to this column  a scatter graph will arrange them in date order. But all will be the same 
"height".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I cannot check this in earlier versions of Excel, but in Excel 2016, if you build a Pivot Table with your data and drop the date in the Rows - you get your data grouped in Years, Quarters, and Months. If you also drop the date into Values, then you get the Count of values in each year, quarter, and month.

Then a pivot chart looks like this ...

[image]

---

**A less magical way to do it**

[Applies to Excel 2013 and up](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Group-or-ungroup-data-in-a-PivotTable-report-c9d1ddd0-6580-47d1-82bc-c84a5a340725)

1. From your single column of dates, build a pivot table.
2. Put the date in Rows. Put Count of date in Values.
3. Select any one of the dates. Right Click and choose "Group...", or choose "Group Selection" from the Analyze ribbon.
4. Click on each of Months, Quarters, and Years.
5. Filter how you would like.
6. Select PivotChart from the Analyze Ribbon.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't seem to be there in Excel 2010, but I might just be not seeing it.

Comment: In 2016 it just happens. Like magic. You can manually group the items in the Pivot Table. [See this](http://chandoo.org/wp/2009/11/17/group-dates-in-pivot-tables/)

Comment: Thanks for that, the group by option **IS** there in 2010 as well once you right click one of the dates.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a scatter graph as suggested in the comment. Consider your data set and see if there is any other quality that could be added to the chart, which could be plotted on the value axis. For example the number of people attending the event, or the duration of the event in seconds, or something like that, so that the graph contains more information. In the following screenshot, the blue dots are just the 1's from column B plotted on the time line. The orange dots plot another data aspect on the vertical axis.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you create a pivot table of the dates and drag the date into the Sums area you will get a count of each day, make sure this is sorted. Then a chart will show the number of records for each day. You will need to copy and past values from the pivot to a new sheet to be able to make a scatter diagram from the output of the pivot table (in Excel 2010). But once it is a scatter diagram the events will  be in the "correct" places.

If you wanted to group it by month instead you could use a formula to create a column of year & month and then do the pivot and chart on that column. For example the formula below will give you 201605 for May 2016.

=YEAR(A2)&RIGHT(100+MONTH(A2),2)

Weeks would be a bit trickier, but I suppose you could divide the date by seven and then INT it to get a 7 day grouping. These wont show the actual events occurance within the period but would let you see which periods have the most events.If you are looking for things like more events at the beginning of the month or something you might need to try different "groupings" like weekly.

[image]